# distribution of max(X,Y)+X+Y, with X and Y iid

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution

I have the following problem. $\theta^A$ and $\theta^B$ are two i.i.d. random variables, with density f and cumulative F. Support is [0,1]. I look at the following variable:
$$b=
\begin{cases}
\theta^A-\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^{\theta^A}F(x)dx + \int_0^{\theta^B}F(x)dx\right) & \text{ if }\theta^B\leq \theta^A\\
\theta^B-\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^{\theta^A}F(x)dx + \int_0^{\theta^B}F(x)dx\right) & \text{ if }\theta^B> \theta^A
\end{cases}$$

So we have

$$
b=\theta_{(1)}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^{\theta^A}F(x)dx + \int_0^{\theta^B}F(x)dx\right)
$$
where $\theta_{(1)}$ is the first order statistics, i.e., $\theta_{(1)}=max\{\theta^A;\theta^B\}$.

I can't apply the classic formula for convolution. 
I need to find the probability density of $b$. Any idea? (If needed we can assume that $f$ is uniform.)

Comment: If $X$ is uniform, then the distribution $F_Y(y)$ of $Y=\int_0^X F(t) dt$ is $F_Y(y)=\sqrt{2y}$. The general case seems rather more complicated.